# Map a collection of custom types on fluent nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a Custom Type on Fluent NHibernate and I need to map it to a collection of its type, using HasMany association. However, Fluent Nhibernate doesn't let me indicate on HasMany that its about a custom type like I do in my regular types.

This is my code:

```
HasMany(x => x.AvailablePaymentOptions)
            .KeyColumn("OFFER_ID")
            .Cascade.None()
            .KeyNullable()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finish not using the custom type, but instead, mapping a component:

```
HasMany(x => x.AvailablePaymentOptions)
            .Table("MY_TABLE")
            .KeyColumn("MY_COLUMN")
            .Component(component =>
                           {
                               //MAP YOUR CUSTOM TYPE HERE
                           })
            .Cascade.None()
            .KeyNullable()
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

Comment: Is this *really* the only way to do it? Because I could as well map my `ICompositeUserType` as component always then... Which is what I do not want to do.